# How do we know Janeway's exact rank in Nemesis?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-nemesis

I have been told, and [Memory Alpha confirms](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Kathryn_Janeway#Later_career), that in Nemesis, Janeway is not only

> an admiral

but also a very high-ranking one. How was this derived? I couldn't find it in the script. Is it something on the uniform?

Comment: In the [script](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Trek-Nemesis.html) she's just described as an admiral; ***ADMIRAL KATHRYN JANEWAY appears on Picard's monitor.  Janeway is the former captain of Voyager.  Her new rank fits her well, she has lost none of her dry humor and down-to-earth charm which made her a household name and beloved cult figure.***

Comment: in the [official novelisation](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_Nemesis_(novel)) she's just described as an admiral; "*Admiral Kathryn Janeway, former captain of the Voyager, looked hale and fit and completely comfortable in her new rank.*"

Comment: At least we can all be confident that Harry Kim is still an Ensign.

Comment: @Fluffysheap - Sorry to disappoint but he got promoted as soon as they came back to Earth.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the film she's wearing the '*three pips inside a box*' rank insignia of a Starfleet [Vice Admiral](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Vice_admiral), a rank that's two steps above Captain, one step above Rear Admiral and one step below Admiral.

[image: Janeway with rank insignia visible, throwing three pips inside a box]

Note that Starfleet ranks are nebulous at best. Suffice to say she's Picard's boss and a replacement for [Admiral Nacheyev](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Alynna_Nechayev) in giving Picard crappy orders.

---

In various EU works she's noted to be a Vice Admiral;

> Kathryn Janeway reveals her career in Starfleet, from her first command to her epic journey through the Delta Quadrant **leading to her rise to the top as vice-admiral in Starfleet Command.** Discover the story of the woman who travelled further than any human ever had before, stranded decades from home, encountering new worlds and species.
>
> <sub><sup>[The Autobiography of Kathryn Janeway](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Autobiography_of_Kathryn_Janeway)</sup></sub>